# Writing a script to chroot into installations and run some commands

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I wrote this little script to help me chroot and do some things on some installations i have. What I can't figure out is how to pass some commands when entering the chroot. for example the way I have it right now it is not running source /etc/profile and it is not exporting the PS1.
Also if you have any fixes feel free.
Thankyou

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvol=@$1 /dev/sda5 /mnt/chroot

for i in dev tmp sys
do
    sudo mount --rbind /$i /mnt/chroot/$i
done

    sudo mount --make-rslave /mnt/chroot/sys
    sudo mount --make-rslave /mnt/chroot/dev
    sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/chroot/proc
    sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/chroot/run

    sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/chroot/etc/resolv.conf

    sudo chroot /mnt/chroot /bin/sh -c "source /etc/profile; bash; export PS1='(chroot) $PS1'"

    sudo umount -R /mnt/chroot
```

Comment: `it is not running source /etc/profile and it is not exporting the PS` it is, there's `source /etc/profile;` right there. If you want to run bash shell,. then run `bash`, not sh. If you want to run a login shell, then add `-l` to sh. And if you want to affect current shell on startup, like chaniging PS line, edit `.bashrc` or edit /etc/bash.bashrc or edit /etc/profile or use `bash --rcfile`.

Comment: sudo chroot /mnt/chroot /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile; export PS1='(chroot) $PS1'"
I tried liek this but it does not work
I dont understand your reply. what I want is that it executes those two commands when it enters the chroot

Comment: They are executed. You do not start an interactive shell.

Comment: how do i fix it to do what i want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit shell configuration. Login shells source /etc/profile.

```
echo "export PS1='(chroot) \$PS1'" >> /mnt/chroot/root/.bashrc
chroot /mnt/chroot bash -li
```

You can also use `--rcfile`, see documentation.